# Passing credentials to a task

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

Hopefully someone can help. I am building an app on Google app engine and trying to pass the credentials of an authenticated user to the push task Handler. I am using the OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets library to create the decorator which seems to store the credentials for the user in the datastore. It stores it with a key name of something like "110111913122157971566". My problem is that I cant seem to find a way to figure out what that key name is so that I can retrieve it using the StorageByKeyName method from within my worker handler. The documentation I have read uses the user_id as the key name but this doesnt work for me as the credentials are not stored with the user_id as the key name, however if I hard code the key name then the code does work. I am aware that I could run the copy code from within the Submit handler but need to run it as a separate task. Below is a sample of my code, thanks for any help you can provide:

```
JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
autoescape=True)

SCOPES =['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
decorator = OAuth2DecoratorFromClientSecrets(    
                                             os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                             'client_secrets.json'),
                                             ' '.join(SCOPES)
                                            )
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):        
    if users.get_current_user():
        url = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        url_linktext = 'Logout'            
        template_values = {'url': url,
                           'url_linktext': url_linktext,
                          }

        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))   

    else:
        self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))

 class Submit(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    @decorator.oauth_required
    def post(self):
      taskqueue.add(url='/worker', params={'user_id' : users.get_current_user().user_id()})
      self.response.write('<html><body>You wrote:<pre>')
      self.response.write(users.get_current_user().user_id())
      self.response.write('</pre></body></html>')

  class Worker(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
      user_id = self.request.get('user_id')
      credentials = StorageByKeyName(CredentialsModel, user_id , 'credentials').get()
      http = httplib2.Http()
      http = credentials.authorize(http)
      service = build('drive', 'v2',http=http)
      fileId = 'actual file_id of drive file here'
      copied_file = {'title': 'My New Test Doc2'}
      new_file = service.files().copy(fileId=fileId,body=copied_file).execute(http=http)

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainPage),
('/submit', Submit),
('/worker', Worker),
(decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler()),
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove the `http=decorator.http` at the top level - it doesn't appear to be used and should only be used from inside the decorated method.

I'm not certain, but looking at the decorator code I think it is is keying based on the user_id().  Your code is displaying that, but the parameter you are passing to the task isn't. Try `{'user_id' : users.get_current_user().user_id()}`.

Comment: thanks for helping. I have removed the `http=decorator.http` and made the change you recommended but unfortunately it didn't help. To give you more context the problem is with the line `credentials = StorageByKeyName(CredentialsModel, user_id , 'credentials').get()`. If I change that to `credentials = StorageByKeyName(CredentialsModel, '110111913122157971566' , 'credentials').get()` then it works because the credentials are stored with that key name and not with the user_id as the key. Problem is that I have no way of knowing that key name when a user first authenticates.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you are not actually passing the user_id to that method. The line where you add the taskqueue: taskqueue.add(url='/worker', params={'user_id' : users.get_current_user()}) needs to changed to pass the user ID, not the user object:  taskqueue.add(url='/worker', params={'user_id' : users.get_current_user().user_id()})  If you did already make that change, can you update the full code in the question above?

Comment: Yeah, I get what you are saying and I have updated the code above with your suggestions. To be honest, in the Submit Handler I am printing out the `users.get_current_user().user_id()` to the screen and it returns nothing whereas `users.get_current_user()` does actually return my email address, but that aside, for some reason the credentials are not being stored with the user_id as the key name which is why I cant retrieve the credentials from storage using the `StorageByKeyName` method and passing it the user_id. If I pass it the key name `110111913122157971566` then it works ok.

Comment: Are you testing locally or deployed?  I've seen the interaction between the users service and oauth2decorator do unexpected things locally.  I was able to confirm that a deployed application is able to successfully get a credentials object back by calling: StorageByKeyName(CredentialsModel, users.get_current_user().user_id() , 'credentials').get()

Comment: My apologies, you were actually correct. I had forgotten ti include the () when calling the user_id() method. It works now. I have updated the code above so that it is now correct. Thanks for your help.